# Commands in batch script not working

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I made the following script:

```
SET localfolder="%~dp0"
mkdir %localfolder%
SET logger="%~dp0"\%~n0.log
echo %date% %time% logger=%logger% >> %logger%

set "list=a b c"
set disk=""

FOR %%i IN (%list%) DO (
    SET disk=%%i: & call :chk
)

:chk
cd C:\windows\system32
%disk% >> %logger%
chkdsk %disk% >> %logger%
```

Running this script file results in the following output:

> 22.12.2014 11:38:36,82 logger="W:\Scripts\"\chkdsk_all.log
>
> W:\Scripts>(SET disk=b:   & call :chk )
>
> W:\Scripts>cd C:\windows\system32
>
> W:\Scripts>b:   1>>"W:\Scripts\"\chkdsk_all.log
>
> W:\Scripts>chkdsk b:   1>>"W:\Scripts\"\chkdsk_all.log
>
> W:\Scripts>(SET disk=c:   & call :chk )
>
> W:\Scripts>cd C:\windows\system32
>
> W:\Scripts>c:   1>>"W:\Scripts\"\chkdsk_all.log
>
> W:\Scripts>chkdsk c:   1>>"W:\Scripts\"\chkdsk_all.log

I don't understand why it doesn't work, what am I missing?

Comment: I expect chkdsk to be performed for each of the listed volumes.
"cd" does not seem to be executed, and neither is chkdsk.

Comment: You can see there's something weird on `echo`ed commands. Should be `SET logger="%~dp0%~n0.log"` (omitted backslash and moved closing `"` quote) and instead of `%disk% >> %logger%` try `echo %disk% >> %logger%`

Comment: And instead `cd C:\windows\system32` try `cd /D C:\windows\system32` or better `pushd C:\windows\system32` with corresponding `popd` in appropriate position.

Comment: You found the problem, JosefZ :) It works after I changed cd C: to cd /D C:. If you add it as an answer, I'll mark it as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after I changed "cd C:" to "cd /D C:"

Answer (score 2):

I've got a few improvements to suggest.

1. `%~dp0` is the drive and path of the directory containing the running script.  I'm puzzled about why you are trying to `mkdir %~dp0` when it is impossible for that directory not to exist already.  Are you trying to create a directory with the same name as the script?  If so, try `md %~dpn0` instead, and `set "logger=%~dpn0\%~n0.log"`.
2. Rather than supplying a static list of drive letters in a `for` loop, why not ask WMI to supply the list?  `wmic logicaldisk where "DriveType=3"` will get you a list of the non-removable, non-network drives in your system.
3. Why are you doing `cd %windir%\system32`?  What ability do you gain by changing to that directory that you don't already have from the script's running directory?  I don't think you need it.
4. You know when you `chkdsk c:` you get an error saying the volume can't be checked while mounted?  I suggest adding `chkdsk /x` to dismount drives first.  In the case of the `C:` drive, you'll probably get "Chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another process.  Would you like to schedule this volume to be checked the next time the system restarts? (Y/N)".  You can go ahead and supply the `Y` ahead of time by piping and `echo Y| chkdsk /x %drive%`.

So here's what I suggest:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "logfile=%~n0.log"

for /f "tokens=2 delims==:" %%I in ('wmic logicaldisk where "DriveType=3" get DeviceID /format:list ^| find "="') do (
    >>"%logfile%" (
        echo Checking "%%I:"
        echo y| chkdsk /x %%I:
    )
)
```

Comment: "'wmic' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

The chkdsk command isn't working for me if I don't enter windows/system32, even from cmd line.

As for chkdsk C:, I'm not getting any such error or prompt.

Comment: What the... From a `cmd` console, enter `where wmic.exe` and `where chkdsk.exe`.  `wmic.exe` should be in `c:\windows\system32\wbem` and `chkdsk.exe` should be in `c:\windows\system32`.  Now enter `path`.  Do you see those two directories in your `%PATH%`?  If not, and if inappropriate to add them for some reason, you could just call `%windir%\system32\wbem\wmic` and `%windir%\system32\chkdsk` as needed.  Those paths not existing in your `%PATH%` is unusual.

Comment: I added %windir%\system32\wbem\wmic and %windir%\system32\chkdsk to the path, but wmic still doesn't work. Chkdsk works better now though :p